# Browser helper object: Navigate method

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, browser-extension

I am developing a browser helper object for internet explorer 11. I want to compare the URL with a string and then navigate to a site. For example, if the URL is "about:blank" the browser should navigate to "www.google.com".

```
InternetExplorer webBrowser;

public void OnBeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
{
    // ???
}
```

How can I implement this? The programming language is C#.